# Downloading blat to M1 mac

Tags: python, macos, anaconda, conda, apple-m1

I am trying to download the blat package so that I can use the GAMMA program to analyze mutations in some sequences. I have bioconda install and I am using one-liner code to download blat described here: https://shanguangyu.com/articles/install-blat-on-mac-with-one-liner-command/

I think the issue could be that blat is not made for M1 macs. I previously had it installed on an older mac but I don't remember how I did that. I am a beginner/proficient coder so it could be an obvious error. Any help is appreciated.

Here is my code:

```
conda install -c bioconda blat
```

Here is my error:

```
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.

PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:

  - blat

Current channels:

  - https://conda.anaconda.org/bioconda/osx-arm64
  - https://conda.anaconda.org/bioconda/noarch
  - https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/osx-arm64
  - https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/noarch

To search for alternate channels that may provide the conda package you're
looking for, navigate to

    https://anaconda.org
```

Comment: Did you search the package?  As shown, only x64 is available https://anaconda.org/bioconda/blat Your link is from 2018, when M1 mac wasn't available

Comment: @SalmanMalik They're not asking for a library recommendation, they're asking why a library they're trying to install fails to do so, which is answerable and perfectly within scope.

Comment: @OneCricketeer I was unclear on their differences. Do you know if it would be possible to run the non-M1 x64 bioconda version on my M1 mac so that I can download those packages? I am assuming the root of my issue might be that it isn't yet available for M1... but it is important that I use this program

Comment: M1 Mac require programs compiled for ARM processors, not amd64. I am not a developer of blat. I cannot tell you if there is an alternative, or what their roadmap is like for supporting new releases. For instance [the last release](https://anaconda.org/bioconda/blat/files) was 4+ years ago.

Comment: Please post your solution as an answer below rather than updating the question

Comment: (in support of the above, see [What is the appropriate action when the answer to a question is added to the question itself?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/267434/what-is-the-appropriate-action-when-the-answer-to-a-question-is-added-to-the-que) on [meta])

Answer (score 1):

You got to the root of the issue. M1 Macs use an ARM64-based architecture as opposed to x64. The [website for blat](https://anaconda.org/bioconda/blat) does not list ARM compatibility, and, addressing the M1 specifically, a quick examination of the last update to the [files](https://anaconda.org/bioconda/blat/files) shows that they predate the launch of the Apple Silicon Macs, just like [the website you got the command from](https://shanguangyu.com/articles/install-blat-on-mac-with-one-liner-command/). Anaconda itself added support for ARM64 [only recently](https://www.anaconda.com/blog/new-release-anaconda-distribution-now-supporting-m1). x64 translation does exist for macOS apps, but I don't think I've heard of one for blat.

Comment: There are some Github issues in bioconda-recipes about them getting ARM credits from AWS for bulid machines

Answer (score 1):

***From post update***

This seems to be a common issue for Python users on new M1 macs. Many python packages are not made for ARM chips

This is solved by downloading `homebrew` and `miniforge` and using this code:

```
CONDA_SUBDIR=osx-64 conda create -n [environment]   # create a new environment
conda activate [environment]
conda env config vars set CONDA_SUBDIR=osx-64  # subsequent commands use intel packages
```

https://naolin.medium.com/conda-on-m1-mac-with-miniforge-bbc4e3924f2b
https://towardsdatascience.com/using-conda-on-an-m1-mac-b2df5608a141
https://github.com/Haydnspass/miniforge#rosetta-on-mac-with-apple-silicon-hardware